# Python 3 авторизация

Tags: python, авторизация

Хочу авторизоваться на сайте moikrug.ru и ходить по ссылкам, писал два способа, но ничего не получилось,

вот первый, тут просто выводится неавторизованная страница

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
url = 'https://passport.yandex.ru/auth?retpath=https%3A%2F%2Fmoikrug.yandex.ru'
r=requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('Мой логин', 'Мой пароль'))
print(r.text)
```

вот второй способ, тут ошибка

```
import urllib.request
import http.cookiejar
import urllib.parse

cookieJar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'login' : 'Мой логин',
                       'passwd' : 'Мой пароль'})

#get = urllib.request.Request('https://passport.yandex.ru/auth?    retpath=https%3A%2F%2Fmoikrug'
#            '.yandex.ru' , params)

f = opener.open('https://passport.yandex.ru/auth?retpath=https%3A%2F%2Fmoikrug'
        '.yandex.ru', params)
h = f.read()
print(h)
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
line 14, in <module>
   '.yandex.ru', params)
TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и в чем проблема?

Answer (score 3):

Во втором случае ошибка связана с тем, что вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `open` с аргументом `params`, который является строкой, а методу нужен аргумент типа байт или коллекция байт. Вам должна помочь следующая конструкция:

`params = params.encode('UTF-8')`

А вообще, я бы не советовал работать с сайтом moikrug.ru таким образом. У сайта есть [API и документация к нему](https://tech.yandex.ru/moikrug/doc/dg/concepts/About-docpage/). Используйте её, это будет наиболее правильным решением.